# Can't cast MapView

Tags: java, android

I am working on android application project, but I keep having problem with casting MapView.
From the logcat,

> Caused by: java.lang.classCastException : com.google.android.maps.MapView cannot be cast to com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView.

And this is my code for casting

```
MapView mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
```

any suggestion?

Comment: Make sure you're only importing one `MapView`

Comment: it's very clear you have different type of object
your casting com.google.android.maps.MapView to com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you only import one `MapView`, and make sure its type matches the one returned by `findViewById`. This is probably caused by an improper import. If your view at `R.id.mapView` is different than the one you're importing, you won't be able to cast it.

So, if your display has a `com.google.android.maps.MapView` but your code imports `com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView`, you won't be able to cast.

Check your import statements, and check your MapView declaration. Make sure the import matches the view.